# MySQL search for duplicate filenames with different extensions

Tags: mysql, substring, filenames

I have a table with ,among other columns, a column called filename, which contains file names with their extension.

I need to find all filenames that have been inserted into the table with the same filename but with different extensions. For example I'm looking for files like

```
01_ceremony_10021.flv
01_ceremony_10021.mp4
```

I need the list of files that exist in both mp4 and flv formats.

I've tried several things like :

```
SELECT 
    archivo, 
    substr(archivo,1, locate(".flv", archivo)-1) as NomSinExt 
FROM videoscampus 
where (substr(archivo, -4) = '.flv' || substr(archivo, -4) = '.mp4' )
order by archivo asc
```

But that just gives me the whole list of videos regardless.

The structure of the table is as follows:

```
Column      Type
-----------------------------
id          int(11) Auto Incr    
filename    varchar(250)     
deleted     int(1)   
dateStart   datetime     
dateEnd     datetime
```

And some examples of filenames that I need to detect:

```
agai_cpal_t6_cristinacoca.mp4    
agai_cpal_t7_ent_ricardomartino_pacoarango.mp4   
agai_cpal_t8_alejandrogonzalez.mp4   
agai_cpal_t9_ent_ricardomartino_barbaradefranceschi.mp4  
AHE_INF_MMijanco_T3_Macronutrientes.flv <---- DUPLICATE I'm looking for
AHE_INF_MMijanco_T3_Macronutrientes.mp4 <---- DUPLICATE I'm looking for
ahe_inf_prim_t10_maitemijancos.mp4   
ahe_inf_t1_maitemijancos.mp4     
ahe_inf_t10_maitemijancos.mp4    
ahe_inf_t10.1_maitemijancos.mp4  
ahe_inf_t10.2_maitemijancos.mp4  
ahe_inf_t11_maitemijancos.mp4    
ahe_inf_t12_javiertejedor.mp4
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

-Orallo

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: At the least, show any queries you have tried that didn't work. Showing the table schema would also be helpful, since we wouldn't have to guess about key column names and such.

Comment: Sorry, I've seldom posted anything on SO and I'm not familiar with the conventions/etiquette. I did of course try to figure it out myself and done quite a bit of googling prior to posting here.  I appreciate the tips on how to properly post a question. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Good updates to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. It splits the table into the mp4 and flv rows, then compares for matches on the first part of each filename.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(a.`filename`,1,LOCATE('.flv',a.`filename`)) as `base_name`,
    a.`filename` as `flv_file`,
    b.`filename` as `mp4_file`
FROM `videoscampus` a
JOIN `videoscampus` b
ON b.`filename` LIKE '%.mp4'
    AND SUBSTR(b.`filename`,1,LOCATE('.mp4',b.`filename`)) = SUBSTR(a.`filename`,1,LOCATE('.flv',a.`filename`))
WHERE a.`filename` LIKE '%.flv'
    AND a.`deleted` = 0
    AND b.`deleted` = 0
```

Comment: Hi Sloan! thanks for your response, your solution was almost perfect.  The query complained about LOCATE taking 2 parameters instead of one, so I just added the filename as the second parameter on each call to LOCATE, and voilá! everything worked like a charm.  Thanks again.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I get a syntax error at line 3: 'SELECT SUBSTR(a. `filename`,1,LOCATE('.nef')) as 'base_name', a.`filename` as '. I tried the post above and still got a syntax error. Any idea?

Comment: Check the revised answer. As @orallo mentioned, the locate function calls were missing the 2nd parameter.